# In what cases can the spectral radius of a matrix and the spectral radius of its absolute value be equated?

Tags: matrices

Let a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is SDD(strictly diagonally dominant). How we can show $\rho(A)=\rho(|A|)$ ($\rho(A)$ represent the spectral radius of the matrix $A$ and $|A|$ represent the absolute value of the matrix $A$). By using Gershgorin's theorem can can we say that $\rho(A)=\rho(|A|)$ for the the non SDD matrix $A$ with positive diagonal entries?

Comment: What do you mean by the absolute value of the matrix?  Elementwise absolute value?

Comment: Yes, the absolute value of the matrix is exactly the elementwise absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true.  For example, the SDD matrix
$$ A = \pmatrix{5 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 5 & 1\cr 1 & -1 & 5\cr}$$ has spectral radius $6$, while $|A|$ has spectral radius $7$.

Comment: This is nice! How did you construct it?

Comment: Well, I know that the spectral radius of a matrix with positive entries and all row sums $=k$ is $k$, so I took one of those and changed one sign.  The fact that the eigenvalues turned out to still be integers is a bit of luck.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought process.

Comment: Thanks for helping to the more clarity the problem by the interesting counterexample.